# How can I create this material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, light

I'm trying to create a Diamond YouTube Play Button in Cycles ( Silver-Plated, with a crystal triangle. I'm struggling to get the accurate result, please tell me the accurate shader for this and some lighting tips. 
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Please use the upload Feature of the site to add the Image to your post. Could you show us, what your progress so far is? Screenshots of your node setup and a preview render would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Download this [Jewelcraft addon](https://github.com/mrachinskiy/jewelcraft)

Install and you can find many shapes in the toolshelf panel with the name of Gems.

Select any 1 gem and below there is a button **Make gem**. Click on it and u get selected gem in the 3d Window. For the material its in build Material with the gems.

[image]